# How to Subscribe to the Blazor.Radzen DialogService onClose event

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I´m using the very helpful [dialog from blazor.radzen](https://blazor.radzen.com/dialog). In the services I created for my models (ModelService), I have a cancel function that rolls back any changes made to my model. This can be triggered using a button inside the dialog like this:

```
<RadzenButton ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Light" Icon="cancel" Text="Cancel" Click="@(args => Cancel(CurrentItem))" />
```

but I need to trigger this function when the dialog closes, so that it cancels the changes made to the model.

The DialogService(Radzen) does offer an OnClose event. it seems to be declared like so:

```
public event Action<dynamic> OnClose;
```

poking around with Visual studio I found this in the metadata of the Dialog Service

```
public class DialogService : IDisposable
    {
        protected List<TaskCompletionSource<dynamic>> tasks;
        protected List<object> dialogs;

        public DialogService(NavigationManager uriHelper);

        public event Action<dynamic> OnClose;
        public event Action OnRefresh;
        public event Action<string, Type, Dictionary<string, object>, DialogOptions> OnOpen;

        public void Close(dynamic result = null);
        [AsyncStateMachine(typeof(<Confirm>d__25))]
        public Task<bool?> Confirm(string message = "Confirm?", string title = "Confirm", ConfirmOptions options = null);
        public void Dispose();
        public void Open<T>(string title, Dictionary<string, object> parameters = null, DialogOptions options = null) where T : ComponentBase;
        public void Open(string title, RenderFragment<DialogService> childContent, DialogOptions options = null);
        public Task<dynamic> OpenAsync<T>(string title, Dictionary<string, object> parameters = null, DialogOptions options = null) where T : ComponentBase;
        public Task<dynamic> OpenAsync(string title, RenderFragment<DialogService> childContent, DialogOptions options = null);
        public void Refresh();
    }
```

I can´t find the signature for the handler so I don´t know how subscribe to the event. I am also wondering where is the best place to subscribe to the event. Should i do it on the OnInitialized?

Comment: The Radzen forum has some posts on this topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[Inject]
protected DialogService dialogService { get; set; }    

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    dialogService.OnOpen += Open;
    dialogService.OnClose += Close;
}

private void Close(dynamic obj)
{
    //throw new NotImplementedException();
}

private void Open(string arg1, Type arg2, Dictionary<string, object> arg3, DialogOptions arg4)
{
    //throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```